# Angular signal result from child to parent

Tags: angular, signals

in Angular, I have been using event emitter to pass a data from from the child component to a parent component to notify the parent component to update a piece of data that I share from the child component to parent component. With Signal being available now in Angular, can I use Signal instead to achieve this? I don't find any examples online. Please help

Answer (score 1):

Yes we can use signals

Example for using signals with inputs in angular 17

**Child Component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  template: `
  <p>Name: {{ username() }}</p>
    <p>Active: {{ isActive() }}</p>`,
  standalone: true,
})
export class HomeComponent {
  @Input({ required: true }) username!: Signal<string>;
  @Input({ required: true }) isActive!: Signal<boolean>;
}
```

**parent component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [HomeComponent],
  template: `
    <app-home [username]="username" [isActive]="isActive" />

    <button (click)="setUsername()"> Set username </button>
  `,
})
export class App {
  username = signal('Hussein');
  isActive = signal(false);

  setUsername(): void {
    this.username.set(Date.now().toString());
  }
}
```

Live example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-fn5rhh?file=src%2Fmain.ts

but it's still limited and personally i don't use it

but in one of the next angular versions we will be able to mark the component as signal `signal: true` like `standalone: true`

check this https://github.com/angular/angular/discussions/49682